# How to trigger click event on a div element and show its neighbour element JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery

I have a lot of divs, they are the same but the data are differen(I use variable(array of objs) and for loop) but these details aren't important

```
                              <div class="item_wrapper">
                                <div class="item_wrapper_info">
                                    <div class="left-line"></div>
                                    <div class="subject">1</div>  <== click here
                                </div>
                                <div class="additional_info"> <== display this block
                                    some text
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I want to achieve this:
If I click .item_wrapper_info div then I want to show .additional_info div

It should be probably done using this keyword.

If I click . item_wrapper_info block I want to find a div with the class name of . additional_info and make display = flex but I don't know how to trigger exactly its . additional_info div.

Probably I can click on .item_wrapper_info > . subject and then show its next neighbour

**SOLUTION**:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".item_wrapper").click(function(){
        var index = $(".item_wrapper").index(this); get index of a certain clicked .item_wrapper element on my page
        $('.additional_info').eq(index).toggle(); using .eq toggle that certain element
    });
})
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code.  Feel free to test it in a runnable snippet.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".item_wrapper").click(function () { 
        var index = $(".item_wrapper").index(this) 
        $('.additional_info').eq(index).css("display","flex");
    });
});
```

Comment: It will trigger all the . additional_info on my page but I need only certain . additional_info.

Comment: I have posted my solution and it works nice

Comment: This one was my answer, I can't approve your one as an answer. But thanks that you have tried